# jwt.io Base-64 Encoded Flag on Non-Base-64 Encoded Secret Works Unexpectedly

Tags: jwt, base64

I am attempting to verify the signature on a JWT token. To do this I paste in my secret to jwt.io, paste my token in afterwards, then check for the signature verified indicator at the bottom of the page. What ultimately ended up as a verified signature was my non-encoded secret, with the base 64 encoded secret flag checked.

My secret is of the form `ABC123_abC123-Abc123-abC` - which contains illegal base 64 characters and is clearly not base 64 encoded, yet jwt.io seems to disagree? What is the reason for this?

Comment: so you first paseted the secret ("base64 encoded secret" NOT checkecd, then the token, it was not verified, then checked "base64 encoded secret" and it got verified? When you change anything on the right side after the token was pasted, the signature will be recalculated and is then automatically verified. And the base64 decoder on jwt.io is obviously extremely tolerant and consumes whatever you offer and just ignores the non convertable characters.

Comment: I repasted my my token to verify after checking the base 64 encoded box, I wish this behavior could be toggled on and off. Sometimes I find it helpful but more often I would prefer it did not work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is some base 64 correction going on under the hood at jwt.io, I put my secret through this tool https://base64.guru/tools/repair and the results of that are seeming to serve my purposes.

'_' was replaced by '/', '-' was replaced by '+', and '=' was added to the end to pad to appropriate length.

Comment: what you describe in the last sentence is just bas64url to base64 conversion. Beside that, jwt.io also ignores wrong characters. If you add "!"§$" as a "base64 encoded secret", you'll get the same result as with an empty secret.